The consumer connected wrong broker in the ActiveMQ Artemis cluster
I have created an ActiveMQ Active cluster that has four nodes: Master1, Master2, Slave1, Slave2. Master1 listened port is 61616 and Slave2 listened port is 61626 on Server A. Master2 listened port is 61626 and Slave1 listened port is 61616 on Server B. When my Spring Boot application starts 153 sessions to connect Master1 by setting spring.artemis.broker-url, I find only 131 sessions on Master2 Web Console. There are 22 sessions connect to Master1. I expect all sessions will connect to Master2. How does consumer connect policy work?
Here is broker cluster setting:
<cluster-connections>
  <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
    <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
    <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
    <static-connectors>
      <connector-ref>Master1</connector-ref>
      <connector-ref>Slave1</connector-ref>
      <connector-ref>Slave2</connector-ref>
      <connector-ref>Master2</connector-ref>
    </static-connectors>
  </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>

I have tried to change connector order in static-connectors or set connectionLoadBalancingPolicyClassName in spring.artemis.broker-url, but these are not work. When I stop Master1, all sessions connect to Master2 correctly.

Why do you expect all sessions to connect to Master2?

Because I set spring.artemis.broker-url with master2 ip and port.

The first thing to note is that the order of connector-ref elements on the cluster-connection has nothing to do with how connections are distributed around the cluster.
The only thing that determines how connections are distributed across a cluster with the default configuration is the clients themselves and this is mainly controlled by the following:

The connection URL specified for the client. For example, is there just one broker listed or multiple brokers?
Once the client makes a connection it downloads the cluster topology and by default it uses that topology for subsequent connection attempts on the same ConnectionFactory instance. This behavior can be disabled by setting useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false on the connection URL.
The connection load-balancing policy determines how entries from the topology are processed for subsequent connection attempts on the same ConnectionFactory instance.

Using Spring here is adding complexity because your application doesn't actually control how the ConnectionFactory is used. All that is delegated to Spring so it's hard to see what's happening at the JMS API level.
All that said, one of the main points of clustering is so that it doesn't matter which node a particular client connects to. If you find that one node is handling most of the connections then you're probably better off simply reducing the size of your cluster (even down to just 1 node) or using a connection router to route connections more deterministically among the nodes.

I specified one broker in connection URL. I will try useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false and connection load-balancing policy. The difficulty we are currently facing is the uneven load between Master1 and Master2. It appears that the load on Master1 is slightly higher. Furthermore, we have observed that the distribution of consumers between Master1 and Master2 is uneven, and consumers are not connecting according to the IP and port settings in the URL. We are unsure if this is the cause of the uneven load.
